# How select from many-to-many association, in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, select, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many association between 'Category' and 'Product' entities in my Entity Framework model.
Take a Look:

[image: Many-to-many]

**The problem:** I don't know how I can select those '**products**, which are *associated* with a given **category**'.

right here I have pseudo-code for what I want:

```
var query = from PRD in MyEFModel.Product
            where PRD.Category.ID == GivenCategoryID
            select PRD;
```

Hope you realized what I need.
It doesn't matter whether to use LINQ or Lambda.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to my question is described thoroughly in [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/).

Anyway, I'm gonna include the code that saved me:

```
var prod = EFModel.Products.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.ID == id));
```

Or even this should work:

```
from s in dc.Products
from c in s.Categories
where c.ID == id
select s;
```

Hope this solves others' problems :)